# How to handle screen manager for multiple interfaces in Python and Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm an early beginner in Python an Kivy and i'd like to build a interface with multiple interfaces.

I decided to start with a very simple application that consist in defying a musical scale.

The first interface (class AskUser) has 2 buttons : scale (class Scale) and tonality (class Tonality).

In the interface scale, the user define the interval of the scale (scale of 7 notes) and in the tonality interface he gives the tonality.

I succeed to program each interface but i didn't succeed 
to launch the interfaces scale and tonality by clicking on the corresponding buttons on the first interface. (see code below)

Does anybody has a simple solution to fix this issue ?
Thank you in advance.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

user_interface=Builder.load_string('''
BoxLayout:
orientation: 'vertical'
Label:
    size_hint_y: 0.2
    font_size: 20
GridLayout:
    padding: 50
    spacing: 10
    cols: 3
    rows: 3
    Button:
        text: 'Scale'
    Button:
        text: 'Tonality'
''')

class AskUser(App):
def build(self):
    return user_interface
 AskUser().run()


class Scale(BoxLayout):
def build(self):
    self.orientation='vertical'
    self.spacing=20
    self.haut()
    self.chiffres()
    self.BoutonValider=Button(text='Valider',size_hint=(0.5,0.15),pos_hint={'right': 0.75},background_color=[0,0,1])
    self.BoutonValider.bind(on_press=self.valider)
    self.add_widget(self.BoutonValider)

def haut(self):
    Layout1=GridLayout(cols=2,size_hint_y=0.2,padding=20)
    scale='Scale=?'
    self.scale=Label(text=scale,font_size=30, color=[1,1,1,1])
    Layout1.add_widget(self.scale)
    self.reponse=''
    self.user_reponse = TextInput(text=self.reponse,font_size=30)
    Layout1.add_widget(self.user_reponse)
    self.add_widget(Layout1)

def chiffres(self):

    Layout2=GridLayout(cols=2,size_hint_y=0.5,spacing=10)

    self.Bouton1=Button(text='1')
    self.Bouton1.bind(on_press=self.nombre)
    Layout2.add_widget(self.Bouton1)

    self.Bouton2=Button(text='2')
    self.Bouton2.bind(on_press=self.nombre)
    Layout2.add_widget(self.Bouton2)

    self.Bouton3=Button(text='3')
    self.Bouton3.bind(on_press=self.nombre)
    Layout2.add_widget(self.Bouton3)

    self.Bouton4=Button(text='4')
    self.Bouton4.bind(on_press=self.nombre)
    Layout2.add_widget(self.Bouton4)

    self.add_widget(Layout2)

def nombre(self,instance):
    self.reponse+=str(int((instance.text)))
    self.user_reponse.text=(self.reponse)

def valider(self,instance):
    reponse=((self.user_reponse.text))
    sum_scale = sum([int(i) for i in str(reponse)])

    if sum_scale ==12 and len(reponse)==7:

        content = Button(text='Scale ok !', font_size=50)
        popup = Popup(title='',content=content, size_hint=(0.5,0.5))
        content.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)
        popup.open()
    else :

        content = Button(text='Not a 12 tones scale !', font_size=50)
        popup = Popup(title='',content=content, size_hint=(0.5,0.5))
        content.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)
        self.reponse=''
        popup.open()

class Tonality(BoxLayout):
def build(self):
    self.orientation='vertical'
    self.spacing=20
    self.haut()
    self.chiffres()
    self.BoutonValider=Button(text='Valider',size_hint=(0.5,0.15),pos_hint={'right': 0.75},background_color=[0,0,1])
    self.BoutonValider.bind(on_press=self.valider)
    self.add_widget(self.BoutonValider)

def haut(self):
    Layout1=GridLayout(cols=2,size_hint_y=0.2,padding=20)
    scale='Tonality=?'
    self.scale=Label(text=scale,font_size=30, color=[1,1,1,1])
    Layout1.add_widget(self.scale)
    self.reponse=''
    self.user_reponse = TextInput(text=self.reponse,font_size=30)
    Layout1.add_widget(self.user_reponse)
    self.add_widget(Layout1)

def chiffres(self):

    Layout2=GridLayout(cols=2,size_hint_y=0.5,spacing=10)

    self.Bouton1=Button(text='c')
    self.Bouton1.bind(on_press=self.nombre)
    Layout2.add_widget(self.Bouton1)

    self.Bouton2=Button(text='c#')
    self.Bouton2.bind(on_press=self.nombre)
    Layout2.add_widget(self.Bouton2)

    self.Bouton3=Button(text='d')
    self.Bouton3.bind(on_press=self.nombre)
    Layout2.add_widget(self.Bouton3)

    self.Bouton4=Button(text='d#')
    self.Bouton4.bind(on_press=self.nombre)
    Layout2.add_widget(self.Bouton4)

    self.add_widget(Layout2)

def nombre(self,instance):
    self.reponse=instance.text
    self.user_reponse.text=(self.reponse)

def valider(self,instance):
    reponse=((self.user_reponse.text))
    if len(reponse)<3:
        content = Button(text='Tonality ok !', font_size=50)
        popup = Popup(title='',content=content, size_hint=(0.5,0.5))
        content.bind(on_press=popup.dismiss)
        popup.open()

class scaleApp(App):

def build(self):

    Panel1=Scale()
    Panel1.build()

    Panel2=Tonality()
    Panel2.build()

    return Panel1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scaleApp().run()
```

Comment: Check out this tutorial on setting up screens with kivy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBUi2HrC-F0

Comment: Thank you for this link, it is helpful for a beginner like me !

Comment: There is also this usefull link ttp://robertour.com/page/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

Builder.load_string('''
<user_interface>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        size_hint_y: 0.2
        font_size: 20
    GridLayout:
        padding: 50
        spacing: 10
        cols: 3
        rows: 3
        Button:
            text: 'Scale'
        Button:
            text: 'Tonality'
''')

class user_interface(BoxLayout):
    pass

class AskUser(App):
    def build(self):
        return user_interface()

AskUser().run()
```